# Python search respective string value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

```
month1=['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12']
month2=['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC']
```

How to search and match of the given string values from these two string arrays?. For example I want my value of 'APR' to be printed if the given value is '04'?. Currently I am using this method;

```
for date1, date2 in zip(month1,month2):
    if date1=='04':
        print(date2)
```

I am trying to avoid using loop for in this case. Is there any other ways on getting the desired result?. Many thanks.

Comment: Use the month list as an integer list like `month1=[0,1,2....11]` then `print(month2[4])`

Comment: you got pandas tag are you using pandas or just normal lists?

Comment: its just a normal list @Yefet

Answer (score 1):

Get index of `"04"` using `month1.index('04')` and then use that index to get name of the month.

```
month2[month1.index("04")]
```